# How To Turn My BlueJ Project Into a Application That Can Run In Console

Tags: java, console, program-entry-point, bluej

We have been learning Java in school, but we aren't very far.  I went ahead by myself and learned how to use the scanner class, and made this project that will use the Pythagorean theorem, and also show work.

We haven't learned how to use static or main, which I know are necessary in Java.  I've tried looking online, but I don't know how to do it without referencing non static content, or a similar error.

Can someone look through my code and tell me the changes I need to make, and also tell me why I need to make these changes for next time?

Edit:  All of the if-else statements are to remove the .0 off of doubles.

Thanks so much.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Solve problems with the pythagorean theorem.  Work included.
 * 
 * @author Andrew Bourgeois 
 * @version 2/7/2014
 */

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Solve problems with the pythagorean theorem.  Work included.
 * 
 * @author Andrew Bourgeois 
 * @version 2/7/2014
 */
public class Pythagorean
{
    public double a;
    public double b;
    public double c;
    public boolean isPlaying = true;
    public Scanner reader;

    public Pythagorean()
    {
        while(isPlaying)
        {
            reader = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input;

            System.out.println("Solve for a, b, c, or quit?");
            input = reader.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();

            if(input.equals("a"))
            {
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Length of b?");
                input = reader.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
                b = Double.parseDouble(input);

                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Length of c?");
                input = reader.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
                c = Double.parseDouble(input);

                a();
            }
            else if(input.equals("b"))
            {
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Length of a?");
                input = reader.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
                a = Double.parseDouble(input);

                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Length of c?");
                input = reader.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
                c = Double.parseDouble(input);

                b();
            }
            else if(input.equals("c"))
            {
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Length of a?");
                input = reader.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
                a = Double.parseDouble(input);

                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Length of b?");
                input = reader.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
                b = Double.parseDouble(input);

                c();
            }
            else if(input.equals("quit"))
            {
                isPlaying = false;
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
    }

    public void a()
    {
        /**
         * Control statements are here to change doubles to ints if the double is a whole number.
         * Code will not work and will end with "NaN = b" if c is less than a.
         */

        //         Line 1
        System.out.println("");
        //         Line 2
        System.out.println("a = ?");
        //         Line 3
        if(b % 1 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("b = " + (int)b);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("b = " + b);
        }
        //         Line 4
        if(c % 1 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("c = " + (int)c);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("c = " + c);
        }
        //         Line 5
        System.out.println();
        //         Line 6
        System.out.println("a^2 + b^2 = c^2");
        //         Line 7
        if(b % 1 == 0 && c % 1 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("a^2 + " + (int)b + "^2 = " + (int)c + "^2");
        }
        else if(b % 1 == 0 && c % 1 != 0)
        {
            System.out.println("a^2 + " + (int)b + "^2 = " + c + "^2");
        }
        else if(b % 1 != 0 && c % 1 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("a^2 + " + b + "^2 = " + (int)c + "^2");
        }
        else if(b % 1 != 0 && c % 1 != 0)
        {
            System.out.println("a^2 + " + b + "^2 = " + c + "^2");
        }
        //         Line 8
        if(b % 1 == 0 && c % 1 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("a^2 + " + (int)(b * b) + " = " + (int)(c * c));
        }
        else if(b % 1 == 0 && c % 1 != 0)
        {
            System.out.println("a^2 + " + (int)(b * b) + " = " + c * c);
        }
        else if(b % 1 != 0 && c % 1 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("a^2 + " + b * b + " = " + (int)(c * c));
        }
        else if(b % 1 != 0 && c % 1 != 0)
        {
            System.out.println("a^2 + " + b * b + " = " + c * c);
        }
        //         Line 9
        if(b % 1 == 0 && c % 1 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("a^2 = " + (int)(c * c - b * b));
        }
        else if(b % 1 != 0 || c % 1 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("a^2 = " + (c * c - b * b));
        }
        //         Line 10
        if(Math.sqrt((c * c) - (b * b)) % 1 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("a = " + (int)(Math.sqrt((c * c) - (b * b))));
        }
        else if(Math.sqrt((c * c) - (b * b)) % 1 != 0)
        {
            System.out.println("a = " + Math.sqrt((c * c) - (b * b)));
        }
        //         Line 11
        System.out.println("");
        //         Line 12
        System.out.println("");

        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        c = 0;
    }

    public void b()
    {
        /**
         * Control statements are here to change doubles to ints if the double is a whole number.
         * Code will not work and will end with "NaN = b" if c is less than a.
         */

        //         Line 1
        System.out.println("");
        //         Line 2
        if(a % 1 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("a = " + (int)a);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("a = " + a);
        }
        //         Line 3
        System.out.println("b = ?");
        //         Line 4
        if(c % 1 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("c = " + (int)c);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("c = " + c);
        }
        //         Line 5
        System.out.println();
        //         Line 6
        System.out.println("a^2 + b^2 = c^2");
        //         Line 7
        if(a % 1 == 0 && c % 1 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println((int)a + "^2 + " + "b^2 = " + (int)c + "^2");
        }
        else if(a % 1 == 0 && c % 1 != 0)
        {
            System.out.println((int)a + "^2 + " + "b^2 = " + c + "^2");
        }
        else if(a % 1 != 0 && c % 1 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(a + "^2 + " + "b^2 = " + (int)c + "^2");
        }
        else if(a % 1 != 0 && c % 1 != 0)
        {
            System.out.println(a + "^2 + " + "b^2 = " + c + "^2");
        }
        //         Line 8
        if(a % 1 == 0 && c % 1 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println((int)a + "^2 + b^2 = " + (int)c + "^2");
        }
        else if(a % 1 == 0 && c % 1 != 0)
        {
            System.out.println((int)a + "^2 + b^2 = " + c + "^2");
        }
        else if(a % 1 != 0 && c % 1 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(a + "^2 + b^2 = " + (int)c + "^2");
        }
        else if(a % 1 != 0 && c % 1 != 0)
        {
            System.out.println(a + "^2 + b^2 = " + c + "^2");
        }
        //         Line 9
        if(a % 1 == 0 && c % 1 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println((int)(a * a) + " + b^2 = " + (int)(c * c));
        }
        else if(a % 1 == 0 && c % 1 != 0)
        {
            System.out.println((int)(a * a) + " + b^2 = " + c * c);
        }
        else if(a % 1 != 0 && c % 1 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(a * a + " + b^2 = " + (int)(c * c));
        }
        else if(a % 1 != 0 && c % 1 != 0)
        {
            System.out.println(a * a + " + b^2 = " + c * c);
        }
        //         Line 10
        if(a % 1 == 0 && c % 1 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("b^2 = " + (int)(c * c - a * a));
        }
        else if(a % 1 != 0 || c % 1 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("b^2 = " + (c * c - a * a));
        }
        //         Line 11
        if(Math.sqrt((c * c) - (a * a)) % 1 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("b = " + (int)(Math.sqrt((c * c) - (a * a))));
        }
        else if(Math.sqrt((c * c) - (a * a)) % 1 != 0)
        {
            System.out.println("b = " + Math.sqrt((c * c) - (a * a)));
        }
        //         Line 12        
        System.out.println("");
        //         Line 13
        System.out.println("");

        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        c = 0;
    }

    public void c()
    {
        /**
         * Control statements are here to change doubles to ints if the double is a whole number.
         */

        //         Line 1
        System.out.println("");
        //         Line 2
        if(a % 1 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("a = " + (int)a);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("a = " + a);
        }
        //         Line 3
        if(b % 1 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("b = " + (int)b);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("b = " + b);
        }
        //         Line 4
        System.out.println("c = ?");
        //         Line 5
        System.out.println();
        //         Line 6
        System.out.println("a^2 + b^2 = c^2");
        //         Line 7
        if(a % 1 == 0 && b % 1 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println((int)a + "^2 + " + (int)b + "^2 = c^2");
        }
        else if(a % 1 == 0 && b % 1 != 0)
        {
            System.out.println((int)a + "^2 + " + b + "^2 = c^2");
        }
        else if(a % 1 != 0 && b % 1 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(a + "^2 + " + (int)b + "^2 = c^2");
        }
        else if(a % 1 != 0 && b % 1 != 0)
        {
            System.out.println(a + "^2 + " + b + "^2 = c^2");
        }
        //         Line 8
        if(a % 1 == 0 && c % 1 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println((int)a + "^2 + b^2 = " + (int)c + "^2");
        }
        else if(a % 1 == 0 && c % 1 != 0)
        {
            System.out.println((int)a + "^2 + b^2 = " + c + "^2");
        }
        else if(a % 1 != 0 && c % 1 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(a + "^2 + b^2 = " + (int)c + "^2");
        }
        else if(a % 1 != 0 && c % 1 != 0)
        {
            System.out.println(a + "^2 + b^2 = " + c + "^2");
        }
        //         Line 9
        if(a % 1 == 0 && b % 1 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println((int)(a * a) + " + " + (int)(b * b) + " = c^2");
        }
        else if(a % 1 == 0 && b % 1 != 0)
        {
            System.out.println((int)(a * a) + " + " + b * b + " = c^2");
        }
        else if(a % 1 != 0 && b % 1 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(a * a + " + " + (int)(b * b) + " = c^2");
        }
        else if(a % 1 != 0 && b % 1 != 0)
        {
            System.out.println(a * a + " + " + b * b + " = c^2");
        }
        //         Line 10
        if((a * a + b * b) % 1 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println((int)(a * a + b * b) + " = c^2");
        }
        else if((a * a + b * b) % 1 != 0)
        {
            System.out.println((a * a + b * b) + " = c^2");
        }
        //         Line 11
        if(Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b) % 1 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println((int)(Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b)) + " = c^2");
        }
        else if(Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b) % 1 != 0)
        {
            System.out.println(Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b) + " = c^2");
        }
        //         Line 12        
        System.out.println("");
        //         Line 13
        System.out.println("");

        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        c = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just insert the following right above your pythagorean() method:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Pythagorean();
 }
```